# Какие языки ближе всего к славянским

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Какие языки ближе всего к славянским?

1. балтийские
2. индоарийские
3. германские
4. греческие
5. романские

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По классической схеме из этого списка наиболее близкими к славянским считаются балтийские, за ними - германские. Потом - романские и греческие.
Что касается индоарийских языков, то их место в этой линейке по степени близости к славянским однозначно установить довольно сложно, поскольку разные критерии дают разные результаты.
С одной стороны, они наиболее близки к праиндоевропейской первооснове, которая в свою очередь находит ближайшего современного родственника в виде балтийского литовского языка, близкого и славянским; с другой - по естественным причинам индоарийские нельзя позиционировать ближе к славянским, чем германские...
Так что лучше их вообще из этой линейки исключить и оставить академикам.

Что же касается балтийских, германских и романских, то известно представление о существовании некой германобалтославянской языковой общности, которая распалась на германскую и балтославянскую, в свою очередь разделившуюся на балтийскую и славянскую. Этим и определяется степень близости.

как-то так...

Answer (score 1):

Балтийские языки. Они, как и славянские, входят в индоевропейскую семью языков. Остальные и рядом не стояли.

Comment: Наверное, имеется в виду балто-славянская группа? В индоевропейскую семью, по-моему, входит весь список ([wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8)).

Comment: Да, Tagirix, Вы как-то очень вольно выражаетесь.